# Fragment Arguments are null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

I am trying to send data from one fragment to another, I am using bundle for that. But, whenever, I try to get any information from that bundle in the second fragment, I get an error message saying that I am trying to get a null object. I have set the arguments of the second fragment before I create it, and I have also add information to the bundle before sending it. I could not find out what is the problem. Here is the interface code in the main fragment which should open the details fragment,

```
 public interface ListClickHandler {

        public void onlistElementClicked ( Bundle args); //we'll have to override it in the parent activity.
    }//end interface.

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);


        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (ListClickHandler) activity;
        }//end try

        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ListClickHandler interface");
        }//end catch
    }
```

Also, I create the bundle in two places, once in the main fragment, which contains a list, if any item is clicked the bundle is created, info is added to the bundle, and that bundle is passed to the method inside the interface as the following,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo_list, container, false);
        mSimpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.notes_row,null, from, to,0);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this); //once this is done onCreateLoader will be called.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notes_list); //findViewById must be called using the rootView because we are inside a fragment.
        listView.setAdapter(mSimpleCursorAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Cursor cursor = mSimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

                    String category= cursor.getString(1);
                    String summary= cursor.getString(2);
                    String description=cursor.getString(3);
                    long id= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesContract.NotesTable._ID));
                    int locationId= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_LOCATION));

                    String [] retrievedData= {category, summary, description};


                    if (getActivity().findViewById (R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
                        //two pane layout:
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putStringArray("data",retrievedData);
                        /*args.putInt("update", 1);*/
                        args.putLong("id", id);
                        args.putInt("locationId", locationId);
                        mCallback.onlistElementClicked(args );/*this is available in the parent activity*/
                    }

                    else {
                       // one pane layout:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotesDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, retrievedData);
                        /*intent.putExtra("update", 1); */ //to indicate that the query should be update not insert.
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        intent.putExtra("locationId", locationId); //whether it is 0 or 1
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }


                }//end outer cursor if.
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

The second place where I create and call the bundle is in the main activity (which contains the main fragment) when some items of the options menu are selected as the following,

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {//open the settings activity to enable the user to change the settings.
            //open settings activity via intent here.
            startActivity(new Intent (this, Settings.class));
            return true;
        }

        if (id==R.id.text_note){  //open the details activity where the user can enter their notes and save it.
            if (twoPane) {
                args.putBoolean("location", false);
                mCallBack.onlistElementClicked(args);
            }
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotesDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true; //this line is necessary
            }
        }//end if

        if (id==R.id.location_note)
        {
            if (twoPane) {
                args.putBoolean("location", true);
                mCallBack.onlistElementClicked(args);
            }
            else {
                //prepare intent here:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotesDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("location", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This is how I override onlistElementClicked in the main activity,

```
@Override
    public void onlistElementClicked(Bundle args) {

        DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
        detailsFragment.setArguments(args); 

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();


    }//end interface method.
```

And this is how I get the information inside the arguments of the details fragment (The fragment that should be opened from the main fragment).

```
Bundle args=this.getArguments();
```

After that I use args to get any information in the bundle, but I am getting the error which I mentioned previously.

Can any one please help me? I've checked several solutions on the web and nothing worked for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Where you call to getArguments?

Comment: where are you calling this Bundle args=this.getArguments(); method ?

Comment: how to do you get those args value, can you post that code? Did you debug and see what value it has?

Comment: And in addition where you create the Bundle?

Comment: @yshahak and @ Preethi Rao, I am calling it in the fragment class and I am assigning that value to the global variable args. So, I can access the arguments from anywhere in the fragment

Comment: Of course you call getArguments()  in the Fragment class but where you call it exactly is the question.

Comment: @Lochana Ragupathy, I get any value inside the args using methods like getStringArray, getBoolean,etc. I pass the key name of each information in the bundle when I call these methods

Comment: please post the code , the place where you create your args

Comment: @ yshahak, actually, I didn't call it in any method, it is called in the body of fragment class, and its value is assigned to a global variable. Is that wrong? thank you

Comment: @Lochana Ragupathy, ok I will. Thanks

Comment: Of course it is wrong. The bundle is pass to the Fragment when it created so the assignment must be in onCreate()

Comment: Yes @yshahak, I tried to vote that up, but I couldn't since I am still a new user. But, the method is not working, I am still getting the same error. Is there any other solution? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the value of Bundle like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    youtBandGlobalMember = getArguments();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @yshahak for your answer, I did that but I am still getting the same error, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.android.notes/com.project.android.notes.NotesList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.containsKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-12. I also tried to do that in the onAttach, but I am getting the same error. Can you please tell me what is the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not really clear. In onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) you use Bundle args. Where the assignments of that Bundle?

Comment: @ yshahak Apologies, but I didn't get your question, I have created the bundle (Bundle args = new Bundle();) inside an if statement, then I set the data inside it using methods like, args.putLong, args.putString, etc. the bundle is only created if the app is running on the tablet, where I want the screen to have the list and the details fragments opened in the same activity, when any item is clicked in the list fragment, the details fragment should set its contents based on the data sent to it in the bundle. Can I send you my code, so you can check it? Please let me know, many thanks to you

Comment: You wrote  if (twoPane) {
                args.putBoolean("location", false);
                mCallBack.onlistElementClicked(args);
            } . where is the creation of that args?

Comment: I defined the args as a global variable in the activity, I did that in the body of the class not inside any method, like this,                                             public class NotesList extends ActionBarActivity implements NotesFragment.ListClickHandler {

    boolean twoPane;
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    NotesFragment.ListClickHandler mCallBack;

Comment: Thank you, but this is similar to my code. Please if there is any other solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Bundle args=this.getArguments();
> ```
>
> actually, I didn't call it in any method, it is called in the body of fragment class, and its value is assigned to a global variable. Is that wrong?

It's too early. Member variables are initialized when the object is constructed and that is before you can call `setArguments()` on the fragment object.

Postpone the `getArguments()` call to one of the `on...()` lifecycle callbacks in the fragment.

Comment: Thanks @laalto for your answer I tried to do that in both onCreate and onAttach callbacks, but I am still getting the same error, can you please tell me how I can solve this problem? Thank you.